# Need 1-4 pins controlling 16pins logic level

Tags: pic, digital-logic, logic-level

I have max four outputs coming from a PIC. I need these four outputs (or one serially) to simultaneously control 16 pins with a logic level. This is for a clock application.

A BCD could accomplish this but I don't believe it is the correct way and no one stocks them.

A set of latches could do this, but that would require me to individually latch each bit and reset when I need to switch the output.

A demux could accomplish this, if one existed that would allow multiple output pins to be high at the same time. Serial to parallel demuxers looked perfect, but all I have found only permit one pin being high at a time.

I'm looking for some type of IC.

Comment: This is just to link a couple of similar threads.  [This one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/38261) and [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/37355).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use one 16 bit shift register (or two 8 bit shift registers connected together). That would require only 3 pins.

- Data
- Clock
- Output latch

You would need a 16 bit variable where you set or clear the bits, then you shift the data through the shift register, and then activate the output latch.

You can use two [74HCT595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf)

Comment: Hm Ok. I initially thought that but did not think it through enough. Clearing the bits in between each set rather than shifting sounds perfect. Thank you Bruno.

Comment: @Mike I'm glad I helped.

Comment: @Bruno - That was *too* easy! I don't think you deserve an  upvote for this :-).  (I did upvote, of course)

Comment: @stevenvh Thanks. All my problems should be as easy as this. :-)