# Creating a keyboard with a microcontroller, do I need an input pin for each key?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, keyboard

I am planning to implement V-USB with an ATMega8 microcontroller. I am interested in implementing an HID device; more specifically, I want to try and make my own simple 26 key keyboard (each corresponding to a letter of the English alphabet).

This may be a stupid question, but do I need an input pin for *each* key I implement? In other words, will I need to use a microcontroller that has at least 26 I/O pins? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Pretty much like this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/multiplexing-inputs-on-a-microcontroller/37362#37362 Also check @stevenvh his elaboration on Charlieplexing If you have 6 inputs, then Charlieplexing allows you \$6 × ( 6 - 1 ) = 30\$ keys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea to use a matrix is certainly the way to go. Your matrix could be organized in another way with eight input rows and four output lines for support of up to 32 switches. Since you only need to excite one input row at a time you could use a simple common 3-8 decoder to drive the input rows like shown below. **This reduces the total microcontroller pin count to 7 lines**!!

Note that with use of a 74HC138 type of 3-8 decoder it is necessary to flip the logic so that the output columns have pullup resistors, the diode direction is inverted and the software will see lows (0's) on the output lines where detected switches are seen.

Many thanks to **tcrosley** for borrowing some of his key matrix graphics and to Philips Semiconductors for the logic symbol image of their 74HC138 part.

[image]

Comment: Nice addition to my circuit -- well, not really mine, I "borrowed" the image from somewhere on the web after searching for keyboard matrix.

Comment: Cool, thanks! The actual concept I had was to make each key a capacitive touch sensor. Would that still be possible with the keyboard matrix method?

Comment: @capcom - The scheme shown is designed for switches that have low impedance contact closures. Capacitive type switches are a whole different type of technology. Contact closure switches including the extremely low cost TACT type push buttons are the type for this matrix solution.

Comment: I see. Well, in terms of low impedance contact closures, do you know what I would be looking for if I was trying to create the thinnest switch possible? That is why I was considering capacitive touch as a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @capcom - To get an idea of how thin you can get a keyboard to be you may want to take apart a computer keyboard to see how they work inside. In keyboards from the recent years the they have three sheets of mylar material. Two sheets in the stack have conductive ink printed on their surfaces facing each other. The third sheet is in between these other two with holes in it where each key site is located. Pressing the two outer sheets together in the area of the hole allows the conductive ink spots that are on the outer sheets to contact through the hole!

Comment: @capcom, by "thinnest switch possible", what exactly do you mean ? Is it thin given the exposed switch profile s.a. how high it sits above the front panel, or profile height over PCB (since you want to keep the entire device very thin) ?  Have you considered membrane switches ?

Comment: That's actually pretty cool! I just wonder if I would be able to implement that at home. Doesn't seem too hard, but I'm not sure. I'll look into it. Please let me know if you know of any other methods to replicate the action of a switch at a minimum thickness. Thanks.

Comment: @icarus74 I literally mean the thinnest switch I can fabricate or purchase (at a decent cost). The height/thickness would be referring to the switch's unpressed position above the surface upon which it is mounted. Thanks for the tip on membrane switches. I looked into them, and they seem to follow the same concept as described by Michael above. Looks promising, thanks.

Comment: @capcom - Quick comment about the typical membrane switch. If implemented as a matrix you will end up without the diodes at each switch position. This is just fine if you expect to use the keypad one position at a time. Afterall the typical membrane switch is not suitable for fast typing. The diodes become essential to permit valid detection of every key at each scan not detect the "phantom key" when three other switches are held down at once.

Answer (score 6):

One of the easiest ways is to use a keyboard matrix, like this one:

[image]

In your case, for 26 keys, you could arrange it in a 5 x 6 matrix (requiring 11 I/O pins).  This will actually allow for 30 keys without any additional wires.  A 6x6 matrix (just one more wire) would permit 36 keys, enough for A-Z and 0-9.

Because of the squaring effect, the larger the keyboard, the more wires you save.  100 keys takes only 20 wires, even less than your running one wire from each of your original 26 keys.

The matrix idea works by scanning: You hold one of the I lines high, one after another, and then scan all of the O lines for each I line held high.   You will get a input high on only one one of the O lines for only one of the I lines held high.  The combination will isolate one of the keys.

Comment: Don't forget pulldown resistors on the "O" lines.