# Is it possible to get a tactile switch with more than two rails?

Tags: switches, button, keypad

Making a button-based input device for my Raspberry Pi. When a pin is pulled to ground it registers a false, so: "if pin 1 = false output = 1".

The problem is I need 30 buttons and I only have 14 pins available. In theory I can do this by having three wires one for each row and ten for each column. Basically making a grid where "if row1 pin = false and pin 1 = false output = 1" or  "if row3 pin = false and pin 2 = false output = 22".

I need something that has three pins that are separate and connect simultaneously upon press. I don't have any idea what the button type I need would even be called. Tact switches are typically bridged in the middle so despite having four pins they are still just have two contacts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or any suggestions on a better way to build this circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the classic *multiplexing* problem, for which the simplest solution uses 11 IO pins, 5 outs and 6 ins (or 6 outs and 5 inputs).

In essence you make just one of the outputs high, and see which inputs are high.  Then you do the next output.  Often this is done with a interrupt on a timer.

Very frequently you can use the same inputs or outputs as you're using for something else that you know won't interfere.

You'll notice that it only works if a single key is pressed at a time, but your code can easily detect overlapping keys and ignore them  (Search about *rollover* if you need to accept overlapping key presses.)  For example, if switches 1 and 8 are both pressed, it is indistinguishable from switches 2 and 7 (or all four) being pressed.

[image: schematic]

If, on the other hand, you need very fast and simultaenous sensing of all the switches, you might try something like some [PCF8574](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/PCF8574(A).pdf) IO expansion chips, which give you eight IO lines per 16-pin chip, and you put them on an i2c bus, such as from your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. I used some of the terms to do a more in depth search and found what I was looking for and this schematic helped too. Problem was I had a general idea of what I needed but didn't know any of terminology and plugging vague descriptions into google wasn't helping. Thank you for your answer, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need buttons with more than two rails.

With 14 pins you can make a 7x7 matrix of 49 standard tactile switches.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you need a keyboard encoder. These devices can encode large numbers of keys (National did one which read 96 keys); output can be many forms, but serial is common. Try a search based on the term.

Answer (score -1):

You can have upto 30 keys on 11 GPIO with normal switches, this is called multiplexing.

Here is a resource that shows a little about [how to do this, and good coding practices](https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/72.php)

Also consider [charlieplexing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/multiplexing-inputs-on-a-microcontroller), though a *little* more complex, it uses less pins

Comment: This would be much more useful as a standalone answer if you put some of the "how to do this" info here instead of relying on an external link.

Comment: @brhans would it be better to include the links in a comment on the question instead of as an answer?

Comment: Comments are disposable suggestions for improvement that are ideally deleted after being acted on. Improvements to the answer should be made in the answer by using the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/641640/edit) link provided for exactly that purpose.

Comment: Include the links, or don't - your choice. My point is that your answer *here* should stand alone and be useful with the information you give *here*, and not rely solely on links to external resources which might change or die - rending your answer of little use.

Comment: Ok, @brhans, got it. I will leave my answer up as it may be useful, even if it isnt fully so